Do shared object files (*.so) need to be built with different bazel rules to run on Android vs Linux?
I'm working on a Unity 3D project that can be built to run on Linux or built to be run on Android. I've written a utility class in C++ that decodes video frames using ffmpeg and named it unity_ffmpeg_decoder.cc. I use bazel to build this C++ code into an .so file to be referenced and used in the Unity application's C# code using a call to DllImport(). Before launching the Unity app for Linux, I run a script which handles creating a symbolic link for the shared object to be used. The functionality works as expected in the Linux build and I can freely use my unity_ffmpeg_decoder utilities in my C# code.
I'm having trouble getting the libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so file to be recognized in the Android application (And the Unity editor for that matter), and I get a DllNotFoundException thrown by Unity.
Here is what I've tried to get it to work:

bazel build the unity_ffmpeg_decoder the same way I did for the Linux app use case.
Copy all of the files generated by that build command into Assets/Plugins/Android (after running build command I see the libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so file, and a folder called libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so.runfiles which contains loads of other *.so, *.a files. Mostly python-related).
Delete any duplicate plugins that Unity detects
Build the APK for android and verify that inside the APK I see libunity_ffmpeg_decoder
Test on device and do not see the .so working as it does in the Linux build.
I've also run ldd libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so within the Assets/Plugins/Android folder and it appears all the dependencies are present.

My questions are the following:

Do I need to change my bazel BUILD file to explicitly state I want to build unity_ffmpeg_decoder for my Android device? Or should the same .so file built for Linux work in an APK?
How would I be able to gain more information from the generic DllNotFoundException thrown from Unity? I can't tell if it's not found because the *.so is missing dependencies, or incompatible, or it literally can't find the *.so in the APK
Do I need to run a command to create a dynamic link for this shared object even though it's included in the APK?
Any easier, less painful solution that's obvious to you?

Here are my code excerpts:
bazel BUILD file
load("//base/rules:cc_rules.bzl", "blum_cc_test")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(
    name = "ffmpeg_decoder",
    srcs = ["ffmpeg_decoder.cc"],
    hdrs = ["ffmpeg_decoder.h"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lswscale",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        "//base",
        "//onboard/comms/utils:video_frame_accessor",
        "//utils/avx2:opts",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "ffmpeg_encoder",
    srcs = ["ffmpeg_encoder.cc"],
    hdrs = ["ffmpeg_encoder.h"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lswscale",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        ":video_utils",
        "//base",
        "//base:scope_guard",
        "//onboard/comms/graph:node_graph_constants",
        "//onboard/comms/proto:camera_cc_proto",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "nvidia_decoder",
    srcs = [
        "nvidia_decoder.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "nvidia_decoder.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        "//base",
        "//base:logging",
        "//onboard/comms/graph:node_graph_constants",
        "//onboard/tegra/cuda:cuda_camera_utils",
        "//third_party/nvidia/video_codec2:nv_decoder",
        "//utils/cuda:cuda_array",
        "//utils/cuda:cuda_surface_object",
        "@local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda_essential",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "nvidia_encoder",
    srcs = [
        "nvidia_encoder.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "nvidia_encoder.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        "//base",
        "//base:logging",
        "//base:status",
        "//blum/status",
        "//onboard/codec/ratecontrol:const_qp_ratecontrol",
        "//onboard/comms/proto:cameragator_params_cc_proto",
        "//third_party/nvidia/video_codec2:nv_encoder",
        "//third_party/nvidia/video_codec2:utils",
        "//utils/cuda:cuda_utils",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "fmp4_encoder",
    srcs = ["fmp4_encoder.cc"],
    hdrs = ["fmp4_encoder.h"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lswscale",
        "-lavformat",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        "//base",
        "//base:scope_guard",
        "//blum/status",
    ],
)

blum_cc_test(
    name = "fmp4_encoder_test",
    srcs = ["fmp4_encoder_test.cc"],
    crosscompile_targets = [
        "nvidia-orin",
    ],
    data = ["data/index.m3u8"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lavcodec",
        "-lavformat",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lswscale",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//base",
        "//blum/status:testing",
        "//onboard/codec:fmp4_encoder",
        "//utils/test:blumtest_main",
        "@opencv//:core",
        "@opencv//:highgui",
        "@opencv//:imgcodecs",
        "@opencv//:imgproc",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "constants",
    hdrs = ["constants.h"],
    deps = [],
)

cc_library(
    name = "video_utils",
    srcs = [
        "video_utils.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "video_utils.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":constants",
        "//base",
        "//blum/status",
        "//onboard/comms/proto:camera_cc_proto",
        "@com_google_absl//absl/strings",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "playback_frame_scenario_builder_cli",
    srcs = ["playback_frame_scenario_builder_cli.cc"],
    linkopts = ["-ldl"],
    deps = [
        "//base",
        "//base/file:blob_image_accessor",
        "//base/file:runfiles",
        "//onboard/codec:nvidia_encoder",
        "//onboard/codec/proto:playback_frame_cc_proto",
        "//onboard/codec/proto:playback_frame_scenario_cc_proto",
        "//utils/files:file_io_utils",
        "@opencv//:core",
        "@opencv//:highgui",
        "@opencv//:imgcodecs",
        "@opencv//:imgproc",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "unity_ffmpeg_decoder_lib",
    srcs = ["unity_ffmpeg_decoder.cc"],
    hdrs = ["unity_ffmpeg_decoder.h"],
    deps = [
        ":ffmpeg_decoder",
        "//guardian:cameras",
        "//onboard/comms:comms_message",
        "//onboard/image:opencv_codec",
        "@Unity//:native_rendering_plugin_headers",
    ],
    alwayslink = 1,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so",
    copts = ["-fPIC"],
    linkshared = 1,
    deps = [":unity_ffmpeg_decoder_lib"],
)

Excerpt from the shell script I run that handles the linking of the shared object (How would I do this when building my APK?)
export PLUGIN_DIR="$DATA/Plugins"
mkdir -p "$PLUGIN_DIR"
ln --force --symbolic \
  "$(readlink -f "$SCRIPT_RUNFILES/blum/onboard/codec/libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so")" \
  "$PLUGIN_DIR/libunity_ffmpeg_decoder.so"

